# Xamarin.Forms - How To Make Left Sidebar Swipe Out and Main Page Slide With It

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, slidingmenu

I'm looking to create a specific animation where you start with a collapsed sidebar (still visible, but skinny) and main page content:

[image]

and when you pull out the left sidebar, the sidebar expands, and the main content moves with it (so that the right part of the main content slides out of view):

[image]

Also, note that the content in the sidebar doesn't move (though there is additional content that appears (button on the bottom)), but rather the width of the sidebar container just expands. Finally, I would like it to slide with my finger, not just be a static animation.

How do I accomplish this in Xamarin.Forms? (Is it possible?)

Comment: Were you able to do the UI as you described?

Answer (score 0):

You can found it in Telerik Xamarin Forms sample (SlideDrawer -> Transitions/Location)

Sign in your account (telerik.com), I thinks it's free ..

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

#### Playing with the Xamarin Studio XAML Preview:

It is a matter of binding your expand event to `WidthRequest` in the first "column" to resize it and push the "right" side over. Depending upon the control settings in the first column, they will either expand to fill the new "column" width or stay a fixed size...

[image]

#### Note: Personally I would do this using `ConstraintExpression`s in order to make the design truly dynamic and adaptive to orientation changes, different screen sizes, etc...

```
<StackLayout RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.25}"
                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.75}"
</StackLayout>
```

#### Example XAML from preview image above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="OpenDrawer.TestLayoutPreview">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Maroon" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">
                    <Button Text="Left 1" BackgroundColor="Aqua"></Button>
                    <Button Text="Left 2" BackgroundColor="Aqua"></Button>
                    <Button Text="Left 3" BackgroundColor="Aqua"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Button Text="Left Bottom" BackgroundColor="Lime"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Right" BackgroundColor="Aqua"></Label>
                <ScrollView>
                    <WebView Source="https://xamarin.com" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" ></WebView>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the slide to go with the finger, rather than being a static animation?

Comment: Of course,you can attach touch gestures and do a swipe, or touch/drag, etc... i.e. within the chosen touch event you can change the request width of the "left panel" and make it track your finger...     https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/